# Magento 2 - How to generate an Interface and a model?

Tags: magento2, api, model, interface

Sometimes i have to create lots of api models, how would I be able to automate that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes i have to create lots of api models, so I created this script Smiley Happy
 This one generates the model

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "provider": "OMNIVA",
    "type": "POST_OFFICE",
    "name": "Abja-Paluoja postkontor",
    "city": "Abja vald",
    "country": "ESTONIA",
    "availability": "E,T,K,R 8:30-13:00 ja 13:30-16:00;N 8:30-13:00 ja 13:30-18:00;L,P suletud",
    "destination_id": 69400,
    "street_address": "P\u00e4rnu maantee 8",
    "postal_code": "69400",
    "coordinate_x": "58.1264356146443",
    "coordinate_y": "25.3548298784361",
    "temp_service_hours": null,
    "temp_service_hours_until": null,
    "temp_service_hours_2": "25.03.2016 suletud",
    "temp_service_hours_2_until": "25.03.2016",
    "comment_et": null,
    "comment_en": null,
    "comment_ru": null,
    "comment_fi": null,
    "comment_lv": null,
    "comment_lt": null
  }';

$name = 'Location';
$vendor = 'Makecommerce';
$module = 'Omniva';


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

$json = $_POST['json'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$vendor = $_POST['vendor'];
$module = $_POST['module'];

$base = "

namespace $vendor\\$module\\Model;
use Magento\\Framework\\Model\\AbstractExtensibleModel;
use $vendor\\$module\\Api\\Data\\{$name}Interface;

class {$name} extends AbstractExtensibleModel implements {$name}Interface
{";


$json = json_decode($json, true);

$base .= '    ';

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $value = strtoupper(preg_replace('|([a-z])([A-Z])|', '$1_$2', $key));
    // $base .= 'const ';
    // $base .= $value;
    // $base .= " = '".$key."';";
    // $base .='
    // ';
    $json[$key] = $value;
}
// $base .= '
//     /**#@-*/
//     ';


foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $base .= '
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function get';
    $base .= ucfirst(preg_replace_callback("/_([a-z])?/", function($match){ return strtoupper($match[1]); },$key));
    $base .='()
    {
        return $this->getData(self::'.$value.');
    }

    ';
}

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {

    $converted = preg_replace_callback("/_([a-z])?/", function($match){ return strtoupper($match[1]); },$key);
    $base .= '
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function set';
    $base .= ucfirst($converted);
    $base .='( $'.$converted.' )
    {
        return $this->setData(self::'.$value.', '. $converted.');
    }
    ';
}


$base .= '
}';
echo "<pre>";

echo $base;
die;
}?>

<form method="POST">
    <label for="json">Json</label>
    <textarea id="json" name="json"></textarea><br>
    <label for="name">Name(before Interface) $name.Interface</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <label for="vendor">Vendor $vendor\$module\Api\Data</label>
    <input type="text" name="vendor" id="vendor"><br>
    <label for="module">Module $vendor\$module\Api\Data</label>
    <input type="module" name="module" id="module"><br>
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```

And this one generates the Interface

```
<?php

$json = '{
    "provider": "OMNIVA",
    "type": "POST_OFFICE",
    "name": "Abja-Paluoja postkontor",
    "city": "Abja vald",
    "country": "ESTONIA",
    "availability": "E,T,K,R 8:30-13:00 ja 13:30-16:00;N 8:30-13:00 ja 13:30-18:00;L,P suletud",
    "destination_id": 69400,
    "street_address": "P\u00e4rnu maantee 8",
    "postal_code": "69400",
    "coordinate_x": "58.1264356146443",
    "coordinate_y": "25.3548298784361",
    "temp_service_hours": null,
    "temp_service_hours_until": null,
    "temp_service_hours_2": "25.03.2016 suletud",
    "temp_service_hours_2_until": "25.03.2016",
    "comment_et": null,
    "comment_en": null,
    "comment_ru": null,
    "comment_fi": null,
    "comment_lv": null,
    "comment_lt": null
  }';

$name = 'Location';
$vendor = 'Makecommerce';
$module = 'Omniva';


if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

$json = $_POST['json'];
$name = $_POST['name'];
$vendor = $_POST['vendor'];
$module = $_POST['module'];

$base = "

namespace $vendor\\$module\\Api\\Data;


interface {$name}Interface
{".
    /**#@+
     * Constants defined for keys of array, makes typos less likely
     */

"";


$json = json_decode($json, true);

$base .= '    ';

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $value = strtoupper(preg_replace('|([a-z])([A-Z])|', '$1_$2', $key));
    // $base .= 'const ';
    // $base .= $value;
    // $base .= " = '".$key."';";
    // $base .='
    // ';
    $json[$key] = $value;
}
// $base .= '
//     /**#@-*/
//     ';


foreach ($json as $key => $value) {
    $base .= '
    /**
     *
     * @return string|null
     */
    public function get';
    $base .= ucfirst(preg_replace_callback("/_([a-z])?/", function($match){ return strtoupper($match[1]); },$key));
    $base .='();

    ';
}

foreach ($json as $key => $value) {

    $converted = preg_replace_callback("/_([a-z])?/", function($match){ return strtoupper($match[1]); },$key);
    $base .= '
    /**
     *
     * @param string|null $'.$converted.'
     * @return $this
     */
    public function set';
    $base .= ucfirst($converted);
    $base .='( $'.$converted.' );
    ';
}


$base .= '
}';
echo "<pre>";
echo $base;
die;
}
?>
<form>
    <label for="json">Json</label>
    <textarea id="json" name="json"></textarea><br>
    <label for="name">Name(before Interface) $name.Interface</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
    <label for="vendor">Vendor $vendor\$module\Api\Data</label>
    <input type="text" name="vendor" id="vendor"><br>
    <label for="module">Module $vendor\$module\Api\Data</label>
    <input type="module" name="module" id="module"><br>
    <input type="submit"> 
</form>
```